# Determine center from two points on the perimeter and radius, need more points for unique solution?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

Given a circle with center $M = (m_1, m_2)$, known radius $R=r$, and two known points **on the perimeter of the circle**, $S_1=(s_{11},s_{12})$ & $S_2=(s_{21},s_{22})$; I am tasked with finding the center, $M$.

[image: Circle with radius and two points known, center coordinates unknown]

I believe that given these two points, the center is uniquely determined by solving the below system of equations for $m_1, m_2$:

$$
R = \sqrt{(s_{11}-m_1)^2+(s_{12}-m_2)^2}
$$

$$
R = \sqrt{(s_{21}-m_1)^2+(s_{22}-m_2)^2}
$$

However, I'm being told that I need an additional point to uniquely determine the center, as what this does is only determine it up to a reflection. I have thus far been unsuccessful in understanding why that would be the case. Can someone help me understand why I need a third point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L$ be the line through your two given points $S_1$ and $S_2.$ If as in your diagram $M$ satisfies the constraints, then the point $M'$ formed by reflecting $M$ through line $L$ also satisfies the constraints.

Added note: There are cases where there is no solution, namely when $2R$ is less than the distance between given points $S_1,S_2.$ Finally if it happens that $2R$ is exactly equal to the distance between $S_1$ and $S_2,$ then there *is* a unique $M$ namely the midpoint of $S_1$ and $S_2$

Comment: Ok, I see it visually and it's convincing, but why aren't two equations determining two unknowns in this case?

Comment: @tvbc For nonlinear equations this can happen. For example consider the two equations $x^2+y^2=2,\ x^2-y^2=0,$ they have any of the four solutions $(x,y)=(\pm 1,\pm 1).$

Comment: @tvbc I added another bit about when the solution doesn't exist or in one case is unique.

Comment: Thank you, this opens up a lot of things I’d like to learn more about! (Never knew that about non-linear equations).  I’m going to mark this as the answer

Comment: @tvbc You're welcome! There's a lot to learn, I'm still learning, and find it fun.